# how to upload image to mysql DB in light weight method in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, uploading

Im simply developing web application which will be use always image uploading to the application.I need allow users to upload image and mean time need to keep ref of uploaded image to my db? any suggestions ?

Comment: use dropzone oru custom file upload

Comment: Thanks for using SO! Unfortunately, your question currently isn't a good fit for the site. We don't write code from scratch, because answers like this are very rarely useful to future visitors. We also don't suggest libraries and frameworks, as these discussions are usually very opinionated. I would encourage you to try different approaches to solving your problem on your own, then post a question about your code if you get stuck. Please take a look at our guidelines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what to include](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).